# Prevent VS 2013 from using a previously logged in User Identity when debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC project I am working on and I notice that my system will save the last logged in user when I'm debugging. Now this can get very annoying since I want to launch debugging as if no user was logged in since I am testing different actions based on whatever role the user logs in under.

I'm guessing that my browser is saving this user as a cookie/session of some sort so my question is, is there a simple way to prevent VS or maybe even some code that will prevent it from using the previous logged in user when I start a debug, then stop and then start debugging again. I hope that's clear enough to understand. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you using forms authentication?

Comment: I am using the built in Identity authentication that comes with it when you create an MVC5 project.

Comment: It's not vs its your browser.  Use incognito mode on chrome or disable history on firefox

Comment: I realize that yes I can use Incognito mode or clear my history but there must be some way to force my Application to not save the login information and that is what I'd like to know

Comment: If you're using a persistent cookie, this will happen.  don't use the persistent cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after researching I have found a solution as to what I was looking for. Basically I can set the cookie to only last for a certain amount of time so when I am done debugging and go back to editing code, the cookie would expire.

The following code was edited inside the Startup.Auth.cs file in my project.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
  AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
  LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
  /*added by me to shorten the time when testing users, 2 minute expiry unless im
  actively using the app then it will slide by another 2 minutes */
  ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 2, 0),
  SlidingExpiration = true
});
```

Now if anybody has a better solution I would love to hear it. I tried to find information regarding ways to configure my Application to only user non-persistent cookies but I could not figure out how so any solutions using that would also be greatly appreciated.